# getting error while sending data using ajax get

Tags: java, ajax, spring

In my Spring-MVC application, I am calling a `.jsp` page using AJAX GET request with passing some data. But I am getting an exception that is posted below. Please help.

**Error**

`WARNING: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.controllers.CustomerController.blankPage(java.lang.String) throws org.json.JSONException`

**AJAX**

```
function blankPage(l) {
                var formData = {
                        name : l
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "/MyApp/blankPage",
                    data : formData
                });
            }
```

**Java**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/blankPage")
    public String blankPage(@RequestBody String patientName) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println(patientName);
        return "redirect:/blank";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/blank", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String blank() {
        return "blank";
    }
```

Comment: What if you use `data: JSON.stringify(formData)` ?

Comment: You're using @RequestBody , shouldn't it be url param?

Comment: For sending FORM data in the AJAX request body, you ought to use POST request. Else, you should send the data in the GET request as URL parameters. GET requests don't carry any payloads.

Answer (score 3):

GET with Request body doesn't make any sense.

make your request as POST request and send the request as Object.

because you are sending a JSON object as a request, not a string.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/blankPage")
public String blankPage(@RequestBody PatientRequest patientName) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println(patientName);
        return "redirect:/blank";
}

@getter @setter
class PatientRequest {
 private String patientName;

}
```